# SQL Выборка из одной таблицы, исходя из другой таблицы.

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет.
Возникли проблемы при составление корректного SQL - Запроса. (Делал с помощью php-библиотеки Active Record, но и запрос стандартного вида тоже будет хорошо).

Есть две таблицы: posts (содержит посты сайта). Имеет колонки: (id,uid,text,pid).
id - идентификатор поста.
uid - id автора поста.
text - текст поста.
pid - id поста из второй таблицы.

Есть вторая таблица: cop (Содержит посты, которые можно заимствовать для реальных постов). Имеет колонки (id,text).
id - идентификатор
text - текст поста.

Задача: Когда происходит вызов функции, делается запрос: выбрать случайный пост для заимствования, который раньше не использовался. То есть, если pid (1 таблица) == id (2 таблица), то не берем. Нужно учитывать автора: где uid = $uid.

Пробовал с помощью Active Record:

```
$query = $this->db->join('posts', 'posts.pid <> cop.id')->get('cop');
```

Нет идей, как сделать этот запрос. Можно сделать запрос вида "SELECT * FROM...", но до этого тоже идеи не доходят. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы выбрать случайную запись из таблицы `cops` исключая вхождения из таблицы `posts` можно составить запрос следующего вида:

```
SELECT `id` 
FROM `cops`
WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT `pid` FROM `posts` WHERE `uid` = '1')
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Данный запрос вернёт тот самый `id`, который ещё не присутствует в таблице `posts`.

---

Если же вашей целью является вставка новой записи в таблицу **posts**, то можно ухитриться и сделать запрос такого вида:

```
INSERT INTO `posts` (uid, text, pid)
VALUES (
  '1',
  'Test Post',
  (SELECT `id` 
    FROM `cops`
    WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT `pid` FROM `posts` as `fake_posts` WHERE `uid` = '1')
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1)
);
```

**P.S.** Обратите внимание, что для вставки я использовал альяс `fake_posts` для таблицы `posts` во вложенном запросе.

> Целевая таблица команды **INSERT** не должна появляться в утверждении **FROM** части **SELECT** данного запроса, поскольку в ANSI SQL запрещено производить выборку из той же таблицы, в которую производится вставка. (с) [mysql.ru](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/INSERT_SELECT.html)

Побаловаться и посмотреть в действии описанные примеры можно тут: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86aa1/11)

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Отличная логика!

Comment: Хотелось бы узнать: если две таблицы будут иметь огромное количество записей, то первый вариант, который Вы показали, будет ресурсоемким? by rand() не сильно ли будет грузить систему?

Comment: @Nick, да этот способ ресурсоёмок для больших таблиц. Как вариант: 

    1) `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cops` и это значение например в $copsCount
    2) $randomCop = mt_rand(1, $copsCount)
    3) в запросе на выборку убираем ORDER BY RAND() и пишем LIMIT $copsCount, 1

Запроса два, но будет в разы быстрее

Comment: Попробовал заменить ORDER BY RAND() Вашим способом - работает не так как нужно. Фишка в том, что выбирается ID из cops любой в принципе. Таким образом, общий запрос как бы "стреляет", нашел или не нашел.

Comment: Да, не подумал об этом. Тогда получается, что надо добавить условие в выборку количества `$copsCount`

    WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT `pid` FROM `posts` WHERE `uid` = '1')

Тогда тут уже нужны нагрузочные тесты - может тут и `RAND` будет норм